# A problem of nonlinear multi-objective optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have two variables x1 and x2 and I use them to calculate 4 metrics y1,y2,y3, and y4. now I want to solve for the value of x1 and x2 so that these four metrics are as large as possible. Can anyone give me some hints? Any method or language is fine.

```
Subscript[y, 1] = Subscript[x, 1]
Subscript[y, 2] = 1/(1 + 1/Subscript[x, 2])
Subscript[y, 3] = (1 - 2*Subscript[x, 1])/(1 + Subscript[x, 2]) + 
  Subscript[x, 1]
Subscript[y, 4] = 2/((1 + 1/Subscript[x, 2]) + 1/Subscript[x, 1])
```

[image]

Boundaries:

```
0 < Subscript[x, 1] <=1
0 < Subscript[x, 2]
0 <= Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 4] <= 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code,not the picture.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please provide copy-paste-able code so that forum participants can experiment with it and assist you further. It is also a good idea to include details on what you have tried out so far.

Comment: This is my first time using Mathematica and I am not sure if my formula code is correct.

Comment: "so that these four metrics are as large as possible"??? What if the first metric is very very good and the other three are bad? Or the first three are good and the last is very very bad? Can you edit your question to describe exactly what single expression you want to maximize? That expression will include y1,y2,y3,y4 in some form. Given that expression people can try to maximize it. I can make y1=1 and y2,y3,y4 smaller and the total of the four is as big as I can find. But I do not know that is what you want.

Comment: I think the fourth metric y4 is the most important, and I hope that y1, y2, y3, and y4 are all greater than 0.5

Comment: {x1,x2,y1,y2,y3,y4}={0.998885,87.2417,0.998885,0.988667,0.987577,0.99375} by doing ten thousand random x1,x2 and saving the largest y1+y2+y3+y4.

Comment: The [DirectSearch](https://www.maplesoft.com/Applications/Detail.aspx?id=101333) package of Maple has tools for this end. E.g. `with(DirectSearch):
f := [x1, 1/(1+1/x2), (1-2*x1)/(1+x2)+x1, 2/(1+1/x1+1/x2)];

constr := [0 < x1, x1 <= 1, max([x1, 1/(1+1/x2), (1-2*x1)/(1+x2)+x1, 2/(1+1/x1+1/x2)]) <= 1, min([x1, 1/(1+1/x2), (1-2*x1)/(1+x2)+x1, 2/(1+1/x1+1/x2)]) >= 0, x2 > 0];
CompromiseProgramming(f, constr)` results in `[x1 = 9.23906243702823*10^(-9), x2 = .999999795207814]`. There are other commands to this end: `BoundedObjective, Minimax, ExponentialWeightedSum, ModifiedTchebycheff`.

Comment: Look in [Multiobjective Optimization: Goal Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some posibilities to maximize

```
(eqs = {Subscript[y, 1] == Subscript[x, 1], 
    Subscript[y, 2] == 1/(1 + 1/Subscript[x, 2]), 
    Subscript[y, 3] == (1 - 2*Subscript[x, 1])/(1 + Subscript[x, 2]) +
       Subscript[x, 1], 
    Subscript[y, 4] == 
     2/((1 + 1/Subscript[x, 2]) + 1/Subscript[x, 1])}) // TableForm

Plot3D[eqs[[3, 2]], {Subscript[x, 1], 0, 1}, {Subscript[x, 2], 0, 
  100}]

cond = Flatten@{0 < Subscript[x, 1] <= 1, 0 < Subscript[x, 2], 
   Thread[0 <= {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], 
      Subscript[y, 4]} <= 1]}
```

Maximize everx yi independently

```
(max1 = Maximize[{#, cond}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], 
       Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y,
        4]}] & /@ {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], 
     Subscript[y, 4]}) // MatrixForm
```

Maximize sum of squared yi

```
sq = {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 
   4]}.{Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[
   y, 4]}

(max2 = Maximize[{sq, cond}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], 
    Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 
    4]}])

(*   {4, {Subscript[x, 1] -> 1/2, Subscript[x, 2] -> 1, 
  Subscript[y, 1] -> 1, Subscript[y, 2] -> 1, Subscript[y, 3] -> 1, 
  Subscript[y, 4] -> 1}}   *)
```

Maximize sum of yi

```
tot = Total@{Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], 
   Subscript[y, 4]}

(max3 = Maximize[{tot, cond}, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], 
    Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 
    4]}])

(*   {4, {Subscript[x, 1] -> 1, Subscript[x, 2] -> 1, Subscript[y, 1] -> 1,
   Subscript[y, 2] -> 1, Subscript[y, 3] -> 1, Subscript[y, 4] -> 1}}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints limit each $y_i$ to be at most $1$.
By choosing $x_1=1$ and $x_2$ large all of them get arbitrarily close to $1$:

```
With[{x1 = 1, x2 = 10000000},
 N[{x1, x2/(x2 + 1), x1 + (1 - 2 x1)/(1 + x2), (2 x1 x2)/(x1 x2 + x1 + x2)}]]
(* {1., 0.9999999, 0.9999999, 0.99999995} *)
```